# kubeadm install flannel get error, what's wrong?

Tags: kubernetes

I install kubeadm (version : v1.13.2 ), after init, I install flannel, it fails, install command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

error is like below.

> Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
>   Resource: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1, Resource=clusterroles", GroupVersionKind: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1, Kind=ClusterRole"
>   Name: "flannel", Namespace: ""
>   Object: &{map["apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1" "kind":"ClusterRole" "metadata":map["name":"flannel" "annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""]] "rules":[map["apiGroups":[""] "resources":["pods"] "verbs":["get"]] map["apiGroups":[""] "resources":["nodes"] "verbs":["list" "watch"]] map["apiGroups":[""] "resources":["nodes/status"] "verbs":["patch"]]]]}
>   from server for: "kube-flannel.yml": clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "flannel" is forbidden: User "system:node:node1" cannot get resource "clusterroles" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
>   Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
>   Resource: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1, Resource=clusterrolebindings", GroupVersionKind: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1, Kind=ClusterRoleBinding"
>   Name: "flannel", Namespace: ""
>   Object: &{map["subjects":[map["kind":"ServiceAccount" "name":"flannel" "namespace":"kube-system"]] "apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1" "kind":"ClusterRoleBinding" "metadata":map["name":"flannel" "annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""]] "roleRef":map["apiGroup":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io" "kind":"ClusterRole" "name":"flannel"]]}
>   from server for: "kube-flannel.yml": clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "flannel" is forbidden: User "system:node:node1" cannot get resource "clusterrolebindings" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
>   Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
>   Resource: "/v1, Resource=serviceaccounts", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=ServiceAccount"
>   Name: "flannel", Namespace: "kube-system"
>   Object: &{map["kind":"ServiceAccount" "metadata":map["name":"flannel" "namespace":"kube-system" "annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""]] "apiVersion":"v1"]}
>   from server for: "kube-flannel.yml": serviceaccounts "flannel" is forbidden: User "system:node:node1" cannot get resource "serviceaccounts" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system": can only create tokens for individual service accounts
>   Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
>   Resource: "/v1, Resource=configmaps", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=ConfigMap"
>   Name: "kube-flannel-cfg", Namespace: "kube-system"
>   Object: &{map["kind":"ConfigMap" "metadata":map["annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "labels":map["app":"flannel" "tier":"node"] "name":"kube-flannel-cfg" "namespace":"kube-system"] "apiVersion":"v1" "data":map["cni-conf.json":"{\n  \"name\": \"cbr0\",\n  \"plugins\": [\n    {\n      \"type\": \"flannel\",\n      \"delegate\": {\n        \"hairpinMode\": true,\n        \"isDefaultGateway\": true\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      \"type\": \"portmap\",\n      \"capabilities\": {\n        \"portMappings\": true\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}\n" "net-conf.json":"{\n  \"Network\": \"10.244.0.0/16\",\n  \"Backend\": {\n    \"Type\": \"vxlan\"\n  }\n}\n"]]}
>   from server for: "kube-flannel.yml": configmaps "kube-flannel-cfg" is forbidden: User "system:node:node1" cannot get resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system": no path found to object
>   Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
>   Resource: "extensions/v1beta1, Resource=daemonsets", GroupVersionKind: "extensions/v1beta1, Kind=DaemonSet"
>   Name: "kube-flannel-ds-amd64", Namespace: "kube-system"
>   Object: &{map["apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1" "kind":"DaemonSet" "metadata":map["annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "labels":map["app":"flannel" "tier":"node"] "name":"kube-flannel-ds-amd64" "namespace":"kube-system"] "spec":map["template":map["metadata":map["labels":map["app":"flannel" "tier":"node"]] "spec":map["tolerations":[map["effect":"NoSchedule" "operator":"Exists"]] "volumes":[map["hostPath":map["path":"/run"] "name":"run"] map["hostPath":map["path":"/etc/cni/net.d"] "name":"cni"] map["configMap":map["name":"kube-flannel-cfg"] "name":"flannel-cfg"]] "containers":[map["name":"kube-flannel" "resources":map["limits":map["cpu":"100m" "memory":"50Mi"] "requests":map["cpu":"100m" "memory":"50Mi"]] "securityContext":map["privileged":%!q(bool=true)] "volumeMounts":[map["mountPath":"/run" "name":"run"] map["mountPath":"/etc/kube-flannel/" "name":"flannel-cfg"]] "args":["--ip-masq" "--kube-subnet-mgr"] "command":["/opt/bin/flanneld"] "env":[map["name":"POD_NAME" "valueFrom":map["fieldRef":map["fieldPath":"metadata.name"]]] map["name":"POD_NAMESPACE" "valueFrom":map["fieldRef":map["fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"]]]] "image":"quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-amd64"]] "hostNetwork":%!q(bool=true) "initContainers":[map["args":["-f" "/etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json" "/etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist"] "command":["cp"] "image":"quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-amd64" "name":"install-cni" "volumeMounts":[map["mountPath":"/etc/cni/net.d" "name":"cni"] map["mountPath":"/etc/kube-flannel/" "name":"flannel-cfg"]]]] "nodeSelector":map["beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64"] "serviceAccountName":"flannel"]]]]}
>   from server for: "kube-flannel.yml": daemonsets.extensions "kube-flannel-ds-amd64" is forbidden: User "system:node:node1" cannot get resource "daemonsets" in API group "extensions" in the namespace "kube-system"
>   Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
>   Resource: "extensions/v1beta1, Resource=daemonsets", GroupVersionKind: "extensions/v1beta1, Kind=DaemonSet"
>   Name: "kube-flannel-ds-arm64", Namespace: "kube-system"
>   Object: &{map["apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1" "kind":"DaemonSet" "metadata":map["name":"kube-flannel-ds-arm64" "namespace":"kube-system" "annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "labels":map["app":"flannel" "tier":"node"]] "spec":map["template":map["spec":map["containers":[map["resources":map["limits":map["cpu":"100m" "memory":"50Mi"] "requests":map["cpu":"100m" "memory":"50Mi"]] "securityContext":map["privileged":%!q(bool=true)] "volumeMounts":[map["mountPath":"/run" "name":"run"] map["mountPath":"/etc/kube-flannel/" "name":"flannel-cfg"]] "args":["--ip-masq" "--kube-subnet-mgr"] "command":["/opt/bin/flanneld"] "env":[map["valueFrom":map["fieldRef":map["fieldPath":"metadata.name"]] "name":"POD_NAME"] map["name":"POD_NAMESPACE" "valueFrom":map["fieldRef":map["fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"]]]] "image":"quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-arm64" "name":"kube-flannel"]] "hostNetwork":%!q(bool=true) "initContainers":[map["command":["cp"] "image":"quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-arm64" "name":"install-cni" "volumeMounts":[map["mountPath":"/etc/cni/net.d" "name":"cni"] map["mountPath":"/etc/kube-flannel/" "name":"flannel-cfg"]] "args":["-f" "/etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json" "/etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist"]]] "nodeSelector":map["beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"arm64"] "serviceAccountName":"flannel" "tolerations":[map["effect":"NoSchedule" "operator":"Exists"]] "volumes":[map["hostPath":map["path":"/run"] "name":"run"] map["hostPath":map["path":"/etc/cni/net.d"] "name":"cni"] map["configMap":map["name":"kube-flannel-cfg"] "name":"flannel-cfg"]]] "metadata":map["labels":map["app":"flannel" "tier":"node"]]]]]}
>   from server for: "kube-flannel.yml": daemonsets.extensions "kube-flannel-ds-arm64" is forbidden: User "system:node:node1" cannot get resource "daemonsets" in API group "extensions" in the namespace "kube-system"
>   Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
>   Resource: "extensions/v1beta1, Resource=daemonsets", GroupVersionKind: "extensions/v1beta1, Kind=DaemonSet"
>   Name: "kube-flannel-ds-arm", Namespace: "kube-system"
>   Object: &{map["apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1" "kind":"DaemonSet" "metadata":map["labels":map["app":"flannel" "tier":"node"] "name":"kube-flannel-ds-arm" "namespace":"kube-system" "annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""]] "spec":map["template":map["metadata":map["labels":map["app":"flannel" "tier":"node"]] "spec":map["hostNetwork":%!q(bool=true) "initContainers":[map["args":["-f" "/etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json" "/etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist"] "command":["cp"] "image":"quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-arm" "name":"install-cni" "volumeMounts":[map["mountPath":"/etc/cni/net.d" "name":"cni"] map["mountPath":"/etc/kube-flannel/" "name":"flannel-cfg"]]]] "nodeSelector":map["beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"arm"] "serviceAccountName":"flannel" "tolerations":[map["effect":"NoSchedule" "operator":"Exists"]] "volumes":[map["hostPath":map["path":"/run"] "name":"run"] map["name":"cni" "hostPath":map["path":"/etc/cni/net.d"]] map["configMap":map["name":"kube-flannel-cfg"] "name":"flannel-cfg"]] "containers":[map["name":"kube-flannel" "resources":map["limits":map["cpu":"100m" "memory":"50Mi"] "requests":map["cpu":"100m" "memory":"50Mi"]] "securityContext":map["privileged":%!q(bool=true)] "volumeMounts":[map["mountPath":"/run" "name":"run"] map["mountPath":"/etc/kube-flannel/" "name":"flannel-cfg"]] "args":["--ip-masq" "--kube-subnet-mgr"] "command":["/opt/bin/flanneld"] "env":[map["name":"POD_NAME" "valueFrom":map["fieldRef":map["fieldPath":"metadata.name"]]] map["name":"POD_NAMESPACE" "valueFrom":map["fieldRef":map["fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"]]]] "image":"quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-arm"]]]]]]}
>   from server for: "kube-flannel.yml": daemonsets.extensions "kube-flannel-ds-arm" is forbidden: User "system:node:node1" cannot get resource "daemonsets" in API group "extensions" in the namespace "kube-system"
>   Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
>   Resource: "extensions/v1beta1, Resource=daemonsets", GroupVersionKind: "extensions/v1beta1, Kind=DaemonSet"
>   Name: "kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le", Namespace: "kube-system"
>   Object: &{map["spec":map["template":map["metadata":map["labels":map["tier":"node" "app":"flannel"]] "spec":map["containers":[map["command":["/opt/bin/flanneld"] "env":[map["name":"POD_NAME" "valueFrom":map["fieldRef":map["fieldPath":"metadata.name"]]] map["name":"POD_NAMESPACE" "valueFrom":map["fieldRef":map["fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"]]]] "image":"quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-ppc64le" "name":"kube-flannel" "resources":map["requests":map["cpu":"100m" "memory":"50Mi"] "limits":map["cpu":"100m" "memory":"50Mi"]] "securityContext":map["privileged":%!q(bool=true)] "volumeMounts":[map["mountPath":"/run" "name":"run"] map["name":"flannel-cfg" "mountPath":"/etc/kube-flannel/"]] "args":["--ip-masq" "--kube-subnet-mgr"]]] "hostNetwork":%!q(bool=true) "initContainers":[map["args":["-f" "/etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json" "/etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist"] "command":["cp"] "image":"quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-ppc64le" "name":"install-cni" "volumeMounts":[map["mountPath":"/etc/cni/net.d" "name":"cni"] map["mountPath":"/etc/kube-flannel/" "name":"flannel-cfg"]]]] "nodeSelector":map["beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"ppc64le"] "serviceAccountName":"flannel" "tolerations":[map["effect":"NoSchedule" "operator":"Exists"]] "volumes":[map["hostPath":map["path":"/run"] "name":"run"] map["hostPath":map["path":"/etc/cni/net.d"] "name":"cni"] map["configMap":map["name":"kube-flannel-cfg"] "name":"flannel-cfg"]]]]] "apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1" "kind":"DaemonSet" "metadata":map["labels":map["app":"flannel" "tier":"node"] "name":"kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le" "namespace":"kube-system" "annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""]]]}
>   from server for: "kube-flannel.yml": daemonsets.extensions "kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le" is forbidden: User "system:node:node1" cannot get resource "daemonsets" in API group "extensions" in the namespace "kube-system"
>   Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
>   Resource: "extensions/v1beta1, Resource=daemonsets", GroupVersionKind: "extensions/v1beta1, Kind=DaemonSet"
>   Name: "kube-flannel-ds-s390x", Namespace: "kube-system"
>   Object: &{map["apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1" "kind":"DaemonSet" "metadata":map["labels":map["app":"flannel" "tier":"node"] "name":"kube-flannel-ds-s390x" "namespace":"kube-system" "annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""]] "spec":map["template":map["metadata":map["labels":map["app":"flannel" "tier":"node"]] "spec":map["nodeSelector":map["beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"s390x"] "serviceAccountName":"flannel" "tolerations":[map["effect":"NoSchedule" "operator":"Exists"]] "volumes":[map["hostPath":map["path":"/run"] "name":"run"] map["hostPath":map["path":"/etc/cni/net.d"] "name":"cni"] map["configMap":map["name":"kube-flannel-cfg"] "name":"flannel-cfg"]] "containers":[map["env":[map["name":"POD_NAME" "valueFrom":map["fieldRef":map["fieldPath":"metadata.name"]]] map["name":"POD_NAMESPACE" "valueFrom":map["fieldRef":map["fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"]]]] "image":"quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-s390x" "name":"kube-flannel" "resources":map["limits":map["cpu":"100m" "memory":"50Mi"] "requests":map["cpu":"100m" "memory":"50Mi"]] "securityContext":map["privileged":%!q(bool=true)] "volumeMounts":[map["mountPath":"/run" "name":"run"] map["name":"flannel-cfg" "mountPath":"/etc/kube-flannel/"]] "args":["--ip-masq" "--kube-subnet-mgr"] "command":["/opt/bin/flanneld"]]] "hostNetwork":%!q(bool=true) "initContainers":[map["args":["-f" "/etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json" "/etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist"] "command":["cp"] "image":"quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-s390x" "name":"install-cni" "volumeMounts":[map["mountPath":"/etc/cni/net.d" "name":"cni"] map["mountPath":"/etc/kube-flannel/" "name":"flannel-cfg"]]]]]]]]}
>   from server for: "kube-flannel.yml": daemonsets.extensions "kube-flannel-ds-s390x" is forbidden: User "system:node:node1" cannot get resource "daemonsets" in API group "extensions" in the namespace "kube-system"

Answer (score 1):

D.TS the problem seems to be in the fact that the previous kube.config is still present on the cluster. 
Try to run:

```
    mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
    sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config #confirm the overwrite with yes + enter.
    sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
    kubectl get nodes
```

and then try to apply Flannel again. You can find more steps required for Kubeadm in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959228/kubectl-apply-yield-forbidden-error-when-retrieving-current-configuration) in case you did not prepare the environment properly.